# SharePoint Online - Automate copy of a document from one folder to another within a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, copy-item

I have to automate moving of one particular document from one folder to another folder with in a SharePoint library (when ever its updated or every Monday). Each time i copy this particular document to another folder i dont want to replace the previously copied document but create a different version of it.

For example if i am copying "Doc1" from folder 1 to folder 2 on every Monday or every time the document is updated. I want all the versions of this document without deleting the older ones.

Any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use the SharePoint's document versioning feature? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-library-3819d2a7-1986-4c77-86f5-a9019fc716e4

Comment: I already have versioning enabled on Folder 1 but the requirement is to keep a copy of all the versions of a specific document in Folder 1 to Folder 2.   @akbarali

Comment: then you can use Event Receiver for this purpose.